# Error submitting to iTunes. CFBundleIcons: AppIcon120x120

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, xcasset

I've got the following error when I submit my app to iTunes with Xcode:
“Ivalid image path – No image found at the path references under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon120x120'”

I'm using xcassets for app icons.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After an hour of modifying plists and recreating assets, it turns out that the problem was with CarPlay icon.
It appears as *AppIcon120x120~car.png* inside the application bundle, but it seems that for some reason Apple validation service expects it to be *AppIcon120x120.png*.

Removing the CarPlay icon fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the CarPlay Icon if you don't want to. I had a similar problem too & it *was* indeed the CarPlay icon that was causing the problem. To fix the problem , I went into my archive & renamed the AppIcon120x120~car.png to AppIcon120x120.png and then it validated without a hitch.